# Prevent JPopupMenu from showing on right click

Tags: java, swing, show, jpopupmenu

I have added a `JPopupMenu` to a `JList`. I use the following code:

```
JList list = new JList();
JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
list.setComponentPopupMenu(popup);
```

**Problem**: the popup appears on right mouse click (which is fine), but it should only do so if the list contains items. If the list is empty and there is no item in it to be right-clicked on, the popup should not show. I have not found a way to solve this.

I know that I could - instead of using the code above - use a custom `MouseListener` to make the popup appear, but the given code example seems to be the suggested way to do it.

Comment: How are you adding items to the `JPopupMenu`?  Set a boolean flag in your application model to indicate whether or not the `JPopupMenu` has items in it.   If so, then set the `JPopupMenu` to the `JList`.  If not, then don't.

Comment: A better design is to allow the JPopupMenu to appear at all times, but disable (some of) its JMenuItems when the list is empty.  Popup menus are invisible, “secret” user interface elements, so users have no way to know when they are or aren’t available.  If nothing happens when right-clicking on an empty list, a user is unlikely to try it again when the list has items.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I thought there might be some on-board functionality to achieve this, without having to remove the popupMenu and add it again every time when needed. But I might go for that approach, then.

I myself thought about disabling all the menu entries before the popup becomes visible on an empty list, but the menu should really appear as a direct response to the items in the list, so I don't want to have a menu popping up when there are no items.